# how to create more than three geany custom commands with shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, geany

Geany allows creating custom commands and first three of them are available for invocation by pressing ctrl+1/2/3 respectively. How to make the fourth and subsequent ones available for shortcuts as well?

Answer (score 1):

By default, only the first three custom commands seem to be bound to shortcuts. This can be changed manually in the preferences.

1. In the menu, select Edit → Preferences.
2. Go to the Keybindings tab.
3. Scroll the keyboard shortcuts list down until you see *Send to Custom Command [N]* entries in the *Format* section. Probably only the first three will be bound to *<Primary>[N]*.
4. Select the command you want to bind to a shortcut and press the *Change* button under the list.
5. Enter the shortcut you want to bind to the command on your keyboard and press OK. Repeat as necessary.

Note that you can bind custom commands to any allowed keyboard shortcuts, not only <Ctrl>[N].

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at http://geany-users.466218.n3.nabble.com/Geany-Users-How-to-Set-Custom-Commands-in-Geany-tp4025693p4025696.html?

From there:

> Hi,
>
> ```
> 1. Open Set Custom Commands dialog
> 2. Click Add button
> 3. Type command name where the cursor is
> 4. Press Enter (required to save the command)
> 5. Click on same row under Label column
> 6. Type a name/label for the command
> 7. Press Enter (required to save the label)
> 8. Click OK button
> ```
>
> To use: Press `<Ctrl>1-9` (depending which number you added)      Or
>   use `Edit->Format->Send Selection To->Your New Command`      Or
>   right-click on editor area for context menu, same as above
>
> Cheers, Matthew Brush

Comment: He Matthew, unfortunately your solution works only for first three commands (<Ctrl>1-3), not for subsequent ones. The question is how to make the rest available by hotkeys.